# Android AlertDialog custom layout distortion

Tags: android, xml, android-alertdialog

Hi I'm wondering about how exactly alertdialogs inflate custom xml layouts? In my example, the xml looks fine when I look at it in the eclipse editor however when the alertdialog builds it i looks completly different. (Sadly I do'nt have the reputation to post screenshots)

Heres the xml. The layout gets pushed up so to speak, so the bottom half of linearlayouts take up maybe 2 thirds of the page even though they have a weight of only 0.40 (ps if anyone could tell me an alternative to all these linearlayouts I would be gratefull!!)
Thank You

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layout_root"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
 >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.20"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.98"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:paddingTop="32dp"
            android:text="Share with..."
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textColor="#00C5CD" >
        </TextView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.02"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <View
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dip"
            android:background="#00C5CD" >
        </View>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.40"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.50"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="0.50"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="0.350"
                android:orientation="vertical" >
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="0.350"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/iv_prev"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:src="@drawable/facebook" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="0.150"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_customize_pill"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:paddingTop="10dp"
                    android:text="Whatsapp"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="0.150"
                android:orientation="vertical" >
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="0.50"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="0.350"
                android:orientation="vertical" >
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="0.350"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/iv_preview3"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:src="@drawable/whatsapp" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="0.150"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_customize_pillsas"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:paddingTop="10dp"
                    android:text="Whatsapp"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="0.150"
                android:orientation="vertical" >
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.40"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="0.50"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="0.150"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="0.350"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_preview4"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:src="@drawable/email" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="0.150"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_customize_pill4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:text="Email"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="0.350"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.50"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Are you serious about this layout file?? So many nested linearlayouts and most of them doesn't even make any sense. i am trying to understand what you want to achieve with this?

Comment: a header, and then underneath want to divide screen in 4. each piece having an image view and a text view. so basically after header screen would be divided in two vertically and horizontally leaving four identical linear-layouts in top left top right as well as bottom left and bottom right.

Comment: No whatever your motive is, what I am saying is that it doesn't make sense. Why do you need a linearlayout around one textview and imageview. It doesn't serve any purpose. purpose of linearlayout is to align two or more child views in one row or column.

Comment: I know it's a very inefficient way of doing things but let me try to illustrate my point. Just say I have a screen and i want an image in its center.I want the ratio of the image to background to stay the same no matter what the screen size is. padding will not do this as dp is all relative (has more effect on a small screen than large) While if you split it up into linear layouts the set an image view to the linearlayout you want than the size of that imageview will always take up the size specied by the parent linear layout, no matter what the screen size

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok for what I understood all you need is like a header and under that a grid like layout right?? If I'm right `TableLayout` might be what you need.

Check this xml and see if it helps you

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingTop="32dp"
        android:text="Share with..."
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="#00C5CD" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="#00C5CD"/>

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="4">

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text="Some text"/>

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text="Some text"/>

            </LinearLayout>

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text="Some text"/>

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text="Some text"/>

            </LinearLayout>

        </TableRow>

    </TableLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: That looks correct thank you, I still don't know how it'll get inflated by alertdialog but if all goes well I will accept answer. Thanks again!

Comment: largely cleaned up the inflated view! Still a few minor issues but they should be manageable! Thanks